# Setting up Intellij with Spring MVC framework

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I've been Googling and reading a lot but I simply cannot add spring framework to my application.

On the IntelliJ website it says simply click 'Add module' and then under technologies select Spring. The only technology I have available is Groovy?!

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Have you already "Added framework support"? What version of IntelliJ?

Comment: I have tried, see this screenshot please: http://postimg.org/image/p1eahf95f/
Also I am using IntelliJ 12

Comment: Are you using the Community or Ultimate edition?

Comment: Community version, only going to produce some personal non-commercial stuff =D

Comment: ... Have you looked at what's supported in the Community edition? http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/index.html Note that you can still use Spring, just not with the deep support IntelliJ adds.

Comment: HAHA, it all makes sense now. How could I have missed that.. thanks for pointing this out.. ouch

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Community Edition of IntelliJ doesn't have the same out-of-the-box support for Spring (and EE development in general) the Ultimate Edition does.

[Features and edition comparison](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/index.html)

You may still use Spring, but you won't get the same IDE integration.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying the offical spring website tutorial with one of these two Youtube videos:

Official Spring website about Intellij:
[Serving Web Content with Spring MVC, Build with your IDE](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/)

Youtube video tutorials on setting up spring with Intellij:
[Spring MVC with Intellij Full Java Config. No web.xml or Servlet.xml](https://www.youtube.com/watch?annotation_id=annotation_2978606867&feature=iv&src_vid=_SOXs4xdurE&v=5BY9YxdMg8I)

or

[Spring MVC application with Intellij Idea (with xml config)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_SOXs4xdurE)